# Is it possible to programmatically create new tables at runtime while using ORM like EF?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible to programmatically create new tables at runtime while using ORM like EF?
Is there an easy or intuitive way to do this?

For example, each time my user creates a new product design, there would be a new table(s) created in the database to store the serial numbers for that product.

Here's some context:

- I am developing an application to manage product serial numbers in a production setting.
- Some products of a given design may eventually be produced on the scale of millions of pieces, each must have a unique serial number.
- Products of different designs may have the same serial number.
- Different products designs have different serial number schema. Some are randomized others are sequential. Ex. (AA00, AA01, AA02... ZZ99) or (IBW8395, YHM4892, UIO0385)
- There needs to be a record of what serials were used for each job. They must be searchable and verifiably unique. Ex. I need to look up a returned product by serial, and determine what production run it came from, when it was produced, etc.

If I want to create randomized serials for a product with schema AA00000, I have to generate all possibilities, and then randomize and place them in a table. Then I will remove them from a table as they are used for production, so they may never be used again for that design. I would then place the used serials in a separate table for record keeping of what serials were used, date, and perhaps other details about the production. For each product design with the example serial schema, there would be 67,600,000 records which amounts to over 500MB of raw data. So it doesn't seem to me to be a good idea to have one table to store all serial numbers for all products. There would potentially be billions of records in that table after a few years.

I've tried searching for a solution to this type of problem, but I haven't found the right thing. Perhaps I am not aware of a common concept about this type of problem. I'm sure that it is a common need.

Comment: Fix your database design... instead of creating a new table per product, use a single serial number table with a foreign key to product.

Comment: agreed. that is just _broken design_ - don't create tables on the fly to "partition" data; just use a single table and filter by a key-column. _if_ you have to do anything on the fly, limit it to views that transparently apply the filter - but i'd recommend using a filtered repository in your code (and not your database) instead.

Comment: 67,600,000 records and 500MB doesn't sound like a lot for a properly architected database.  I agree with Dale and Franz; I don't think you need this capability.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's a per-product number. OP is concerned about ending up with billions of records over the long run.

Comment: I agree that 67 million records isn't a lot, but that is for just one product. This database would eventually store data for hundreds or thousands of products, resulting in Billions of records. Would this become unreasonable from a performance perspective?

Comment: @JeremyStewart: Question is: if there are going to be hundreds or thousands of products, how are you planning to manage that in Entity Framework? You don't want to have to add a new entity property to your code every time a new product is introduced, do you?

Comment: Well, if this is an actual need, the way you do it is with Raw SQL Queries.  You can use DDL to do whatever you want.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_ExecuteSqlRaw_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Object__).

Comment: I'd like to add, that as far as the schema used by EF, that doesn't fundamentally change. Only the table would change. I'd like to avoid filtering millions of records for each query, based on a foreign key lookup.

Comment: SQL Server can handle that many records with correct indexing and or partitioning.

Comment: Is the problem filtering or is the problem table size?  Because filtering is not a problem if table size is not a problem.  A properly indexed foreign key is just as fast on a large table as it is on a small one.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, You're getting at the heart of my question. I was hoping that EF had some kind of mechanism for the a single property to point to a table while the other properties would still function with the same schema pointing to columns within that dynamically swapped table. If that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and answers. I feel reassured that the eventual size of the data and number of records wouldn't be a problem for the database.

Comment: I very much doubt it.  What you're proposing is custom, and outside of the purview of Entity Framework.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for [Partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15), which happens at the SQL Server layer, not at the Entity Framework layer. It seems to me like you're going to need to do some performance testing to see how well SQL Server scales with your anticipated use case. Start with the simplest strategy and do some analysis, then try a few other approaches until you get sufficient performance.

Comment: It also seems that storing the serial number data in the filesystem and just organizing the metadata with EF would be a more reasonable approach.

Comment: Agreed. Or a separate document-based database technology. There are a lot of possible tools you may be able to leverage, but until you've identified the use cases and what kind of performance you need from them, it's hard to know which one is best-suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> each time my user creates a new product design, there would be a new table(s) created in the database to store the serial numbers for that product.

No.  A new *row* would be inserted in a Product table, and serial numbers would be inserted as they are created in a ProductSerialNumber table with Primary Key (ProductId,SerialNumber).  The serial numbers could be generated by whatever logic you want, and would be unique per ProductId.

> If I want to create randomized serials for a product with schema AA00000, I have to generate all possibilities, and then randomize and place them in a table.

Or you could generate a random serial at runtime, with retry if it already exists.  You wouldn't expect a large number of retries in the number of serial numbers you want to generate.  The only reasons I know to do this are to prevent guessing or mis-keying a serial number from resulting in a valid serial number, and so you only want to generate a small fraction of the possible values.

Or you could use a SEQUENCE object to generate a random-looking number with arithmetic or with a single mapping table.

Comment: The collision rate will be far higher than you anticipate.  The schema AA00000 produces 67,600,000 possibilities. With the very last product, each guess at an unused serial has one chance in 67.6 million of succeeding. Even very early into the run, the birthday problem dictates significant collisions.

Comment: Just for fun, I implemented the random serial number approach entirely in memory. The first million are found in 534 ms. The 36th set of one million unique serial numbers took 16.5 seconds. The 37th set of one million has been running for 4 minutes now and counting (all CPU constrained... plenty of free memory and no IO involved).

Comment: In this domain the “first million” is probably overkill.  Otherwise add a zero to the serial number format.

Comment: Maybe, but why opt for a strategy with terrible worst-case performance?

Comment: Because "to generate all possibilities," has terrible best-case performance.

Comment: Yeah, pregenerating all combinations is like going to take FOREVER to start.

Comment: I hate it when I have to pre-generate every possible GUID. If only there was a better way...

Comment: Yep.  Pretty keys are a mess.

Comment: Thanks for all of the great responses. I have already determined that pre-generating all possibilities is far less resource hungry, than checking each new serial against a used serial table. It only takes a few minutes on my i7 laptop. There absolutely would be collisions if we were generating these on the fly. The more we produce, the greater the possibility of collision. The resource need exponentially increases as the table fills.

Comment: @ Eric J. I'd be very interested to see how you implemented your generator for the serials.

Comment: @ David Browne. I really appreciate your insight. I agree that what I proposed is a "broken design". However, I am looking for a way to avoid having billions of records. I suppose that a properly designed database shouldn't have performance issues because of this.

Comment: What mechanism is there for generating "random" appearing serials like this on the fly without having to check against a list? What I mean is, is there a way to feed a generator algorithm a seed and an index and have the next "random" serial generated? The same seed and index would result in the same serial each time. No two index's per seed would produce a duplicate.

Comment: Yes.  The simplest are to take a sequential int seeded starting at a large number and apply a bit shuffle. But there are more sophisticated algorithms.